# How to set the scroll direction for RTL languages like arabic, persian etc in lvgl 7.11?

Tags: c, fonts, graphics, lvgl

We have set the auto bidirectional flag for RTL language. how the scroll should be for RTL language.
flag LV_LABEL_LONG_SROLL_CIRC is working fine for LTR language like english etc.

I tried RTL language to display using scroll_circ flag.

lv_label_set_long_mode(label, LV_LABEL_LONG_SROLL_CIRC);